# why does the script affect everything on my Rails 3 app even when cased in this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a third party script which is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thirdpartysite.com/front.asp?id=xxxx"></script>
```

What the script does is put a watermark on an image to show that it is copyrighted.

This is the code that I'm using in view, but no matter what, the script applies to all posts

```
<% if post.copyright == true %>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://thirdpartysite.com/front.asp?id=xxxx"></script>
    <% else %>
    <% end %>
```

When I test it using text only, it works correctly

```
<% if post.copyright == true %>      
        Sample text here only applies to post where copyright==true
        <% else %>
        <% end %>
```

How can I get the script to only apply to certain posts?

Comment: and how does the script work? Maybe it applies to all pictures?

Comment: Let me clarify my original post... there are multiple posts on the page. There's a listing of 10 posts per page (some have images and some don't). Of the images some have copyright ==true and those are the only ones I want to run the script on. I tried applying the `<% if post.copyright == true %>` but all images are affected

Comment: Combine the two methods above and see what happens. If your statements are correct that should be mathematically equivalent of dividing by zero.

Comment: @ted, I'm not 100% how the script works as I was just given that script code from the 3rd party site. I thought that I could make the script run only on certain images by encasing it in some code....

Comment: any other ideas? I'd highly prefer to just apply this script as it works perfectly... except it applies page wide even when trying to individualize it

Answer (score 0):

After your clarified in a comment

Yeah, including javascript will apply pagewide if nothing else is specified in the javascript.

You need to do something like:

```
<div class="post <%= 'copyright' if post.copyright%>">
  <img src="somesrc.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

and then apply the javascript only to the css selector 'div.copyright img'. Something along the lines of that. Depends on what the javascript supports or if you can change the source.

Comment: do you mind clarifying the answer? still not completely sure how to apply the javascript correctly

Comment: FYI - I am not able to change the source of the script

Comment: If you can't change the javascript then you probably can't make it work. The javascript file doesn't care where you put the script-tag, it's applied pagewide no matter what.